# While loop returning duplicate result in php

Tags: php, json

I am working with a JSON file that is nested and I am employing a JSON pull parser for PHP 7 due to the size of the file. I want to extract data and put them in a csv table as thus:

```
 `FOO ID`        `NAME`        `UHC`     `UHCCOMPANY`
 `foo_1403039`   `bana`        `nege`    
 `foo_1403039`   `baan`
 `foo_13589`     `anab`        `neeg`    `nege`
 `foo_13590`     `naab`
 `foo_1403220`   `suresh ltd`
 `foo_1403223`   `suresh ltd`
```

But then if you notice in the table above, the 1st and 2nd data (foo_1403039) under the first column titled `FOO ID` are duplicated, and I do not want that. Indeed, if I delete the 1st data under the first column, and shift the cell of that column up by one step, the table looks perfect. Similarly, the last two data (suresh ltd) under the under the second column titled `NAME` are also duplicate.

I do not know what is wrong in my code. Any help will be appreciated. Here is [my dummy json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdHpPVXFQM1pWeUE/view?usp=sharing), and this is my php code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php';
 use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
 $reader = new JsonReader();
 $reader->open("myjsonfile.json");
 $fo = fopen("mycsv.csv", "w" );
 fputs($fo, "companyID1, name, ultimateHoldingCompany,  uhcCountry".PHP_EOL);
 while($reader->read()) {
 if (preg_match('/^foo_/', $reader->name())){
  $companyID = $reader->name();
  $companyID1 = str_ireplace("foo_","",$companyID);

if ($reader->read("entityName")){
    $entityName = $reader->value();
    $entityName = str_ireplace(","," ",$entityName);
}

if ($reader->read("ultimateHoldingCompany")){       
    $uhcName = null;
    $uhcCountry = null;
    $ultimateHoldingCompany = $reader->value();

    if (empty($ultimateHoldingCompany)){
    }
    else {
        $uhcCountry = $ultimateHoldingCompany[0]['country'];
        $uhcName = $ultimateHoldingCompany[0]['name'];
        $uhcName = str_ireplace(","," ",$uhcName);
    }

}       
fputs($fo,   $companyID1.",".$entityName.",".$uhcName.",".$uhcCountry.PHP_EOL);
}
}
$reader->close();
```

Comment: Wow 40GB? Somebody is trying to make databases obsolete?

Comment: @Barns52 and it seems to be a fast growing data set at that - a week ago they apparently were at 27GB ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697523/php-json-first-and-last-loop-duplicate-result

Comment: I like to help were I can, but must draw the line bad practice. With this chunk of data you really must use a database engine in order to work efficiently. Any system trying to parse a 40GB file (or any file in the GB range) will kill your systems performance.

Comment: Hi, the question I posted is not an issue of trying to parse the 40GB, it is about issue with looping. I am able to deal easily with the 40GB json file using stream parser without problem. Stream parsers can deal with even bigger files. It is possible these days to parse huge file in different ways even without using database engine, particularly if you casually need to extract small amount of data from a huge data, without necessarily maintaining a database. Even working with file size of 360kb, I am having issue with looping. Thus, the question here is about looping and not parsing.